# Array day in x minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have a code that divides my day block X according to the variable tempoConsulta**

```
var tempoConsulta = 25;
var dt = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0)

while (dt.getDate() == 1) {
  var point = dt.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
  dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + tempoConsulta);
  console.log(point)
}
```

I set the **variable dt** that my day starts at **09:00**, but I want the day to end at **19:00**, so my while or for would have to be from **9:00 to 19:00**, can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: then don't check `getDate() == 1`. check `getHour() == 19`

Comment: It does not work, already tried

Comment: I decided
 while (dt.getDate() == 1) {if(dt.getHours() < 19){}}

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to divide your time range from 9:00 to 19:00 in 25 (or whatever is stored in `tempoConsulta`) minute slots.

You can do this by basing your condition on `dt.getHours()` instead of `dt.getDate()`. Try doing something like,

```
var tempoConsulta = 25;
var dt = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0)

while (dt.getHours() >= 9 && dt.getHours() < 19) {
    var point = dt.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
    dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + tempoConsulta);
    console.log(point)
}
```